# Combing multiple dictionaries with the same key appending their values

Tags: python, dictionary

Im using Python 3.9. I need to merge multiple dictionaries with list values into appending the array value to each key

```
{'xx5.8.38': ['testingxyz-597247']}
{'xx5.8.38': ['testingxyz-597624']}
{'xx5.8.38': ['testingxyz-597626']}
{'xx1.0.3': ['testingxyz-597247']}
{'xx1.0.3': ['testingxyz-597624']}
{'xx1.0.3': ['testingxyz-597626']}
(several more dicts)
```

Result should be:

```
{'xx5.8.38': ['testingxyz-597247', 'testingxyz-597624', 'testingxyz-597626']}
{'xx1.0.3': ['testingxyz-597247', 'testingxyz-597624', 'testingxyz-597626']}
```

Comment: And what is the question? Which part of this task is not working for you? Do you have some code which does not work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

input_dirs = [{'xx5.8.38': ['testingxyz-597247']},
              {'xx5.8.38': ['testingxyz-597624']},
              {'xx5.8.38': ['testingxyz-597626']},
              {'xx1.0.3': ['testingxyz-597247']},
              {'xx1.0.3': ['testingxyz-597624']},
              {'xx1.0.3': ['testingxyz-597626']}]


result_dir = defaultdict(list)
for single_dir in input_dirs:
    for key, val in single_dir.items():
        result_dir[key].extend(val)
```

giving you

```sh
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {'xx1.0.3': ['testingxyz-597247',
                         'testingxyz-597624',
                         'testingxyz-597626'],
             'xx5.8.38': ['testingxyz-597247',
                          'testingxyz-597624',
                          'testingxyz-597626']})
```